# Why was the restriction on the comma operator being in a constant expression removed in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++03, constant-expression

Recently when [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27297736/1708801) I realized that the *comma operator* is allowed in a constant expression in [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) as long as the expression is surrounded by `()`, for example:

```
int a[ (1, 2) ] ;
```

[Pre C++11](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf) it is forbidden to use the *comma operator* in a constant expression, from the draft pre C++11 standard section `5.19` *Constant expressions* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]In particular, except in sizeof expressions, functions, class
>   objects, pointers, or references shall not be used, and assignment,
>   increment, decrement, function-call, or **comma operators shall not be
>   used.**

Why was the comma operator not allowed in a constant expression pre C++11 and why was this restriction lifted?

Answer (score 20):

We can find the answer to this in the [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-discussion) group [Comma operator in constant-expression](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-discussion/constant$20expression$20comma/std-discussion/tXL0RNFSlK4/WpLSAV0PTGwJ) thread where Gabriel Dos Reis says:

> For C++11 I proposed to allow it because the restriction appeared
>   arbitrary and all reasons I've heard as rationale for its ban appear
>   very unconvincing and specious to me.

and Richard Smith [earlier in the thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/tXL0RNFSlK4/SI9nvqGVpusJ) notes some of the uses of the *comma operator* in a *constant expression* in both C++11 and C++14:

> I disagree with your argument and your conclusion. In C++11, the comma
>   operator is useful within constexpr functions, because we aren't
>   allowed multiple statements:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>   constexpr T my_array<T>::at(size_type n) {
>   return (n < size() || throw "n too large"), (*this)[n];   }
> ```
>
> In C++14, it's useful in essentially all of the cases where it's
>   useful outside of constant expressions:
>
> ```
> constexpr void do_stuff(int x[]) {
>   for (int i = 0, j = 100; i != j; ++i, --j)
>     x[i] = x[j];   }
> ```
>
> More philosophically, we shouldn't ban things from constant
>   expressions simply because we're not imaginative enough to find the
>   cases where they're genuinely useful. Constant expressions should not
>   be a semi-random sublanguage of C++, missing random features, to the
>   extent that we can avoid that. These days, top-level commas are
>   prohibited mostly because constant-expressions tend to occur in
>   contexts where a comma would mean something else.

Note it was argued that his C++11 example is not correct since the the expression containing the *comma operator* should be in `()` but his example gives the essence of the argument. The argument would be based on the grammar from  section `5.19` *Constant expressions*:

```
constant-expression:
   conditional-expression
```

we can not get to *comma operator* from a *conditional-expression* but we can get to *primary-expression* which gets us to `( expression )` and we can then get to the *comma operator* from *expression*.

T.C. [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324573/why-was-the-restriction-on-the-comma-operator-being-in-a-constant-expression-rem#comment43111378_27324574) that this may not be the case since the relevant section seems vague on this point.

Comment: I would probably explain also why the `()` is required in C++11 (it's the grammar, which requires a *conditional-expression*).

Comment: @T.C. Fair point, I am commuting and won't be able to do a real edit for a bit but I address that in the [link I provide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297736/1708801) in the question above.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure if Richard Smith's C++11 example is incorrect. An invocation of a `constexpr` function is a *conditional-expression* and hence fits the grammar, so the question is whether the invocation, "when substituted by function invocation substitution", produces a constant expression, and the spec in [dcl.constexpr]/p5 is wonderfully vague about the exact expression produced by *function invocation substitution*.

Comment: @T.C. Hmmm, interesting question. He did not disagree with that assessment during the discussion but that does not mean it is correct. I would have to think about that.

Comment: Whether his example `constexpr` function was correctly written or missing a pair of parentheses, I don't see how that affects Richard's point that allowing the comma is useful for `constexpr` functions.

Comment: So I'm not sure what "Although I would argue Richard's point does not make much sense otherwise." is about?

Comment: @T.C. I see how that was not clear now, I removed that sentence.